# python3 bot.py django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet

Tags: python, django, heroku, telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot witch depends on a Django app, I'm trying to deploy it on Heroku but I get this error

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

when it runs python3 main/bot.py in Heroku

here is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn telega.wsgi
worker: python main/bot.py
```

main/bot.py:

```
import telebot
import traceback
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_FLOOR
import requests
import json
from django.conf import settings
from preferences import preferences
from main.markups import *
from main.tools import *

config = preferences.Config
TOKEN = config.bot_token

from main.models import *
from telebot.types import LabeledPrice

# # #
if settings.DEBUG:
    TOKEN = 'mybottoken'
# # #

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

admins = config.admin_list.split('\n')
admin_list = list(map(int, admins))


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    user = get_user(message)
    lang = preferences.Language
    clear_user(user)

    if user.user_id in admin_list:
        bot.send_message(user.user_id,
                        text=clear_text(lang.start_greetings_message),
                        reply_markup=main_admin_markup(),
                        parse_mode='html')
    else:
        bot.send_message(user.user_id,
                        text=clear_text(lang.start_greetings_message),
                        reply_markup=main_menu_markup(),
                        parse_mode='html')


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == preferences.Language.porfolio_button)
def porfolio_button(message):
....
...
```

and my settings.py:

```
"""
Django settings for telega project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/
"""

import django_heroku
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'sw)pfb7&!l98xdoxn9(hy4eacwm33tj1vknyhz#tmv3mr-@ueo'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost',
                 "https://olk-telegram-bot.herokuapp.com"
                 "olk-telegram-bot.herokuapp.com",
                 "www.olk-telegram-bot.herokuapp.com",
                 "olk-telegram-bot"
                 ".herokuapp.com",
                 ]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'preferences',
    'main',
    'ckeditor',
    'dbbackup',  # django-dbbackup
]

DBBACKUP_STORAGE = 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
DBBACKUP_STORAGE_OPTIONS = {'location': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "backup")}


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'telega.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'telega.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 3600,
        'NAME': 'portfolio',
        'USER': 'mysql',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'PASSWORD': 'mysql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',
        },
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [
#     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
# ]

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'enterMode': 2,
        'linkShowAdvancedTab': False,
        'linkShowTargetTab': False,
        'toolbar': 'Custom',
        'toolbar_Custom': [
            ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline'],
            ['Link', 'Unlink'],
            ['RemoveFormat', 'Source']
        ],
    }
}


# Activate Django-Heroku.
django_heroku.settings(locals())

del DATABASES['default']['OPTIONS']['sslmode']

SITE_ID = 2
```

I don't know if I'm doing right or no, it'll be appreciated if you guide me through :)

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` under `INSTALLED_APPS` you need to do `app_name.apps.AppNameConfig`.

So if you app name was `telegram_bot` you would do `telegram_bot.apps.TelegramBotConfig`.

Comment: my app called `main` but there is no TelegramBotConfig class in apps

Comment: i dont know what should i put in there

Comment: this app is currently working on digitaloceans server, its only not working in Heroku

Comment: No worries. We've all been new at some point. Unfortunately, if it is working on DigitalOcean and not Heroku, it is probably something with the version of Python on the server. Can you check the Python version on the server and see if they are different?

Comment: it both uses python 3

Comment: Look at the `bot.py` syntax, 
```from main.markups import *
from main.tools import *```

these are wrong? when i try to run the bot localy it says no module `main`, i should probably use `.` instad of `main` but it cause error again...

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I should run `polling.py` not `main/bot.py` -__-